# OnclickListener not working on small screen sizes?

Tags: java, android, onclick

So I have some code that sets an onClickListener for a button that doesn't seem to work on devices with screen sizes less than 4 inches, but only for specific buttons. I'm not sure why, because it doesn't seem to be an effect OS Level version, but only screen size.

I have logging code in the onclick method that shows all the buttons registering and firing correctly except the new_game button. Any input on why this might be happening would be appreciated.

Code from OnCreate:

```
Button acknowledgements = (Button) findViewById(R.id.acknolwedgments_word_Game);
acknowledgements.setOnClickListener(this);
Button quit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.quit_word_game_button);
quit.setOnClickListener(this);
Button new_game = (Button) findViewById(R.id.word_game_new_Button);
Log.e("NEW GAME BUTTON", String.valueOf(new_game));
new_game.setOnClickListener(this);
Log.e("SET ONCLICK", "DONE");
```

OnClickListener:

```
public void onClick(View view) {
    int id = view.getId();
    Log.e("CLICKED BUTTON", String.valueOf(view));
    if (id == R.id.quit_word_game_button){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Game.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.acknolwedgments_word_Game){
        Intent i = new Intent(this, Acknowledgements.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
    else if (id == R.id.word_game_new_Button){
        final AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(word_game_mainscreen.this).create();
        final EditText edit = new EditText(getBaseContext());
        edit.setHint("Username");
        alert.setView(edit);
        alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                alert.dismiss();
            }
        });
        alert.setButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "PLAY!", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                final String opponent = String.valueOf(edit.getText());
                new AsyncTask(){

                    @Override
                    protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
                        //Code to synchronize it to a server
                    }

                    @Override
                    protected void onPostExecute(Object o) {
                        super.onPostExecute(o);
                        Log.e("POST EXECUTE", (String)o);
                        //Creates intent to take you to the game
                    }
                }.execute();
            }
        });
        alert.show();
    }
    else if (id == R.id.togglesound){
        ToggleButton music = (ToggleButton) findViewById(R.id.togglesound);
        if (music.isChecked()){
            Music.play(this, R.raw.wordgame);
        }
        else{
            Music.stop(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Turns out I had an unpopulated scroll view that was placed over the button on low density screens of small sizes. Nothing wrong with the code above (outside of it being bad formatting at least).

Answer (score 0):

Simple suggestion: `swith` case is far better than `if-else` and `class_name.this` is mostly friendly than `getBaseContext()`.

For showing [AlertDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html) we have to first create the builder.Something like:

```
AlertDialog dialog;
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setIcon(...).setTitle(...)
.setView(...)
.setPositiviButton(...)
.setNegativeButton(...);

//Now create the builder and assign to AlertDialog
dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show;
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did convert the AlertDialog builder but the same results show up, with it working on my phone and other large screen devices but not on smaller screen emulators.